# Convert VARCHAR to Date with different date formatted - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field that thas 2 different formats of date, I want it to be in the same format so I can do a TO_DATE.

### CURRENT

```
DATE|FORMAT|DATA_TYPE
2020-12-15|YYYY-MM-DD|VARCHAR
12/16/2020|MM/DD/YYYY|VARCHAR
```

### EXPECTED

```
DATE|FORMAT|DATA_TYPE
2020-12-15|YYYY-MM-DD|DATE
2020-12-16|YYYY-MM-DD|DATE
```

I have tried below

```
TO_DATE(ACQUIREDDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: In the EXPECTED, the values are DATE data type. DATE values don't have a format. They are DISPLAYED according to your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter.

Comment: Thinking back to the solution I posted. In the CURRENT, do you mean that the format is stored in your table, in a separate column? Or do you **only** have the "date" string, and the format must be guessed? If so, do you know for sure that the formats must be one of the two you show, or can they be *anything at all*? If it's the latter, the problem cannot be solved; if the string is 11-12-2020, how do you know if it's November 12 or 11 December?

Comment: This is an absolutely terrible design! Do you have any control over it? If so, I **HIGHLY** recommend you have a column that's of DATE datatype and convert your strings into dates (using `to_date(<string>, <format>)`) on insert. That way, when you select from it, you can convert to whatever format you like using `to_char(<date>, <format>)`. This is by far the simplest and least risky way of doing things, and you're also not reinventing the wheel this way!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two formats, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when date like '%-%-%' then to_date(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             else to_date(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        end) as real_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `to_date()` can be an expression, just like the first argument - it doesn't have to be hardcoded (it doesn't have to be a string *literal*).

In particular, if the date format is stored in a separate column, you can pass that in as the second argument.

In the illustration below, first I set the date format I want to use for my session. Then I show the query - including a WITH clause (not part of the solution!) just to provide testing data.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-MON-yyyy';

with
  my_table (acquireddate, dtformat) as (
    select '2020-12-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD' from dual union all
    select '12/16/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY' from dual
  )
select acquireddate, dtformat,
       to_date(acquireddate, dtformat) as my_date
from   my_table
;

ACQUIREDDATE DTFORMAT   MY_DATE    
------------ ---------- -----------
2020-12-15   YYYY-MM-DD 15-DEC-2020
12/16/2020   MM/DD/YYYY 16-DEC-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` function (Introduced in Oracle 12.2) as follows:

```
SQL> -- sample data
SQL> with your_table (date_col) as (
  2  select '2020-12-15' from dual union all
  3  select '12/16/2020' from dual
  4  )
  5  -- Query starts from here
  6  SELECT DATE_COL,
  7         TO_DATE(DATE_COL, -- Your table's column name
  8                 CASE WHEN VALIDATE_CONVERSION(DATE_COL AS DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 1
  9                      THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' -- format of the column according to VALIDATE_CONVERSION
 10                      ELSE 'MM/DD/YYYY' -- format of the column according to VALIDATE_CONVERSION
 11                 END) AS DATE_DERIVED
 12    FROM YOUR_TABLE;

DATE_COL     DATE_DERIVED
----------   --------------------
2020-12-15   15-DEC-2020 00:00:00
12/16/2020   16-DEC-2020 00:00:00

SQL>
```